# User inputs specific set of number and random number from the set is outputted

Tags: java, random, numbers, user-input

I have a java code that randomizes a number from a specific set, i want to be able to have the user inputs the specific set such as: {1,6,400,500} and the output is randomized from these numbers, how would i do that?, here is the code i have:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
 
public class Randomizer {
 
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
 
        
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
 
        
        list.add(1);
        list.add(24);
        list.add(77);
        list.add(90);
        list.add(80);
        list.add(1790);
 
        Randomizer obj = new Randomizer();
 
      
        int boundIndex = 3;
 
        
        System.out.println(
            obj.getRandomElement(list, boundIndex));
    }
 
  
    public int getRandomElement(List<Integer> list,
                                int bound)
    {
       
        return list.get(
            ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(list.size())
            % bound);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Random java util:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(24);
    list.add(77);
    list.add(90);
    list.add(80);
    list.add(1790);
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomInt = list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));

    System.out.println("Random int from list = " + randomInt);
}
```